# Помогите ребят с командой бан на телефоне в Дискорд команду делал в Bot Designer For Discord

Tags: discord, бот, fail2ban

Когда я пишу команду вместе с юзером и причиной у меня бот пишет это: x Function $ban returned an error: Failed to ban user!

Comment: А что именно непонятно из текста ошибки "Failed to ban user" (Не удалось заблокировать пользователя)?

Answer (score 0):

`Failed to ban user` Говорит о том, что боту не удалось заблокировать пользователя. На это есть несколько причин:

1. У бота недостаточно прав
2. Пользователя нет на сервере, где его нужно забанить
3. Права пользователя выше прав бота(например бот пытается забанить создателя сервера)